# Как отправить сообщение ботом в определенную беседу вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
vk.messages.send(message = f'{message.content}', random_id = get_random_id())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указать параметр [`peer_id`](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B):

```py
PEER_ID: int = ...

vk.messages.send(
    random_id=get_random_id(),
    peer_id=PEER_ID,
    message=f'{message.content}',
)
```

Для групповой беседы:

- `2000000000` + `id` беседы

Comment: Так же есть параметр `chat_id` для бесед. Подробнее можно посмотреть в документации по этому [методу](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send).